# Unable to connect in IPv6 network iOS GCDAsyncSocket

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, app-store, appstore-approval, cocoaasyncsocket

I have a game which uses `socke`t based connections. It wrok well in an `IPv4 network`.

We submitted an update to the App Store and it got rejected saying the game doesn't work under `IPv6 networks`. Our game backend is using `AWS`.

When I gone through many forums I came to know that AWS is not IPv6 ready.

For client I'm using `CocoaAsyncSocket`. I've disabled `IPv4PreferredOverIPv6`. But is not working.

Can you please suggest a better solution?

Comment: Hi Kumar, could you please mention the version of AWS SDK for iOS which you are currently using? The latest one is 2.4.3 and is the recommended SDK to be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GCDAsyncSocket to connect to an IPv4 address literal, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/issues/429) that has already been fixed in the latest commit in the CocoaAsyncSocket repository 2 weeks ago. Make sure you are using the latest revision.

The latest revision, plus setting `IPv4PreferredOverIPv6` to `NO`, should work.

Comment: I've set the flag to `NO`. But it's not working. I got this error.

Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=65 "No route to host" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No route to host, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Error in connect() function}

Comment: @KumarChikkanna: And you've checked out the latest revision from the repo?

Comment: @user102008 as of 3/7/16 it's still only a PR it's not been accepted onto trunk,

Comment: @Keab42: Hmm, I might have been looking at the wrong branch (or maybe they altered the branches since I looked?); it was committed in the `ipv6` branch